# MailboxExportRequest ContentFilter Date ignored

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm running into an issue on our exchange server 2016 CU23Oct23SU. Problem: I'm not able to export e-mails on some accounts using ContentFilter, some are working, but the settings for both of them are the same. Here is what I'm currently doing, with privacy related information obscured.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Threading")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Globalization")
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")

$mailboxname = "import@mydomain.tld"
$datum = "03/03/2022"
$deletefilter = "01/01/2000.." + $datum
$jobname = $mailboxname + "-" + ($datum.Replace("/", "."))
$filepath = "\\exchange\G$\export_temp\" + $jobname + ".pst"

New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $mailboxname -Name $jobname -ContentFilter {(Received -lt $datum) -or (Sent -lt $datum)} -FilePath $filepath -BadItemLimit 1000
```

As it worked for the last mailbox, in this case the whole mailbox (~100GB, this is why I'm trying export it partly and delete this data afterwards) is exported.

Any help is appreciated / thanks in advance!

Tried to use any available resources from Microsoft and the web / nothing helped for these mailboxes.